# not getting parseInt to work on knockout.js (NaN error)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to do some calculations through knockout.js but I'm getting a NaN error.

This is the code:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    aanvoerSl25mm = ko.observable();
    lengtePrijs125mm = 1;

    totaalAanvoer = parseInt(aanvoerSl25mm*lengtePrijs125mm);


}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

totaalAanvoer gives me NaN as output.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FullContCoder/3TUsp/2/

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: aanvoerSl25mm is a function.

Comment: Hi Attila, thanks for your quick answer! Could you elaborate a bit how I have to change the code to get a number and not NaN? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems:

1. As attila said, `aanvoerSl25mm` is a function (observables are functions), so you need to get the value out using `aanvoerSl25mm()`
2. You haven't provided `aanvoerSl25mm` with a value, so its current value is undefined. You should create it with a value such as `aanvoerSl25mm = ko.observable(0);`
3. You are only calculating the value once (immediately). What you want to do is to make a computed function (see [the documentation here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)). This will mean the computed value will change automatically when the observable changes. For example:

   `totaalAanvoer = ko.computed(function() {
        return parseInt(aanvoerSl25mm()*lengtePrijs125mm);
    });`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. And atilla too of course.